# How to prevent double quotes on HTML entities from string?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm using Symfony 1.4 and have a string in *action* and set this string in *variables*:

```
<div class='paging_links' name='initiatives'>
    <span class='active' name='1'>1</span> 
    <span class='' name='2'>2</span> 
</div>
```

Then in *template*, convert `<?php echo html_entity_decode($pagination) ?>` produces the following:

```
<div class="'paging_links'" name="'initiatives'">
     <span class="'active'" name="'1'">1</span> 
     <span class="''" name="'2'">2</span> 
</div>
```

But I need the class name without double quotes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it
`html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_XML1, 'UTF-8')`